# Font-Styles, ToolBox to use in C# for TextBoxes - Text

Tags: c#, fonts

I'm searching a script or a toolbox in C#, where
the User can change his own Textstyle, after or while writing in a TextBox..

Just like here I can change the style:

**BOLD**

*Text*

And change Colors, TextSize and and and..

Hope u can show me a link or something similiar

Comment: Do you mean TextBox or RichTextBox?

Comment: Normal Multiline TextBox or would you recommend to use RichTextbox? There I think its possible to do something like that: richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment look at the RichTextBox

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx

You might also want to look at this:

http://www.digitalrune.com/Products/WindowsForms/TextEditorControl.aspx

This is an open source control for text editing and you would be able to look at the code I think

Comment: so and how can I handle the problem with the Colors? I don't wanna make foreach color a ImageButton and then Setting the richtextbox property manually..

Comment: I have updated my answer with a free open text editing control that allows coloring.  Being open source I would expect the code to be available

Comment: coloring, but the User its self should be able coloring, not me in the CodeBehind^^ but anyway thx for the answer, will mark it as done